# Windows 11 Startup Profiles

Tags: windows, windows-11

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. The only answers I found seem to be too old and refer to options that either no longer work or are no longer available.

I have a laptop that I mostly use in my home office connected to a dock with several peripherals attached and their management apps startup with Windows. 1-2 times a week I spend some time in the office and I find that I have to spend time shutting down all the startup apps for those peripherals when I'm not at home. I some cases, it's not just a case of wasted CPU cycles, they can cause issues if the devices aren't there.

Optimally, I'd like to setup some profiles (e.g. home/work/travel) that control which apps (possibly even services) launch at startup. Ideally, I would be able to define the profiles, define what starts in each profile, and define a default profile that would launch after a timeout period, so I don't have to babysit every single boot/restart. I'm open to either a built-in Windows option or a third-party utility, paid or otherwise.

If more info is needed, I'm happy to provide it. If this is a duplicate, please point me to the right post, and I'll happily close this post. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What you describe isn’t a feature of Windows. Best you could achieve is NOT installing applications to all user profiles, but there are ramifications, for doing that and still wouldn’t actually achieve what you describe

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by removing certain items from *automatic* startup (see Russinovich's [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for a full listing). Then create two scripts to start the desired services and application, label them *Home* and *Office*, and put them on the desktop to start manually.

Another possibility would be to create two different users, and putting startup items in `C:\Users\<user1>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and in `C:\Users\<user2>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Of course, that means that applications must be installed for *all* users, or installed twice, once for each user.

*Caveat:* These workarounds won't allow use of Hibernation and Sleep. If on Hibernates at home, the machine will start up configured for home use whilst at the office, and *verse visa*.